# React JS Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

new to react and running through a tutorial here.  https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_complex_components.htm

I am getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token" right after the return function of my Card class.  I am new to web development and am trying to get going in the right direction.  I downloaded react dev tools for chrome but it permanently says Waiting for roots to load...

This error usually comes from a syntax error so I assume there is something wrong with my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    #container {
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">


  var Card = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var cardStyle = {
          height: 200,
          width: 150,
          padding: 0,
          backgroundColor: "#FFF",
          WebkitFilter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)",
          filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
        };

        return (
          <div style={cardStyle}>

          </div>
        );
      }
  });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <Card/>
      </div>,
      document.querySelector("#container")
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, it works with this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/72515/

Comment: I have also copied and pasted your example into my own `.html` file and it loaded just fine

Comment: Thanks guys, must be something on my computers end then.